# How do I put a word instead of a link in the browser bar in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm looking for a way to hide the link in the browser bar and show the word instead. Like this:

[image: An example of my question]

I am using this code in an Android application to open a page on a website, and I want to show a word instead of the link address of the website.

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Browser.OpenAsync("https://www.google.com", new BrowserLaunchOptions
    {
        LaunchMode = BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred,
        TitleMode = BrowserTitleMode.Show,
        PreferredToolbarColor = Color.FromHex("131416"),
        PreferredControlColor = Color.Violet,
    });
    // await Navigation.PushAsync(new WebView(), true);
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your issue clearly? Do you mean you want to hide the `Title` of the browser, if so , you can try to set `BrowserTitleMode.Hide`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean, and I tried this code, but without any change

Comment: May I know what's the version  of your `Essential` , have you updated to the latest visions?